# How to disable Stackdriver Monitoring for a project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-stackdriver

After receiving the email from Google about billing changes for Stackdriver Monitoring, I'd like to disable this for our project because we're not currently using it.

Is it possible to disable the Monitoring (not Logging) across an entire GCP project and if so how?

Doc's don't seem very clear on this and there's nothing I can see in the normal Cloud Console, or the Stackdriver one.

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the project from your stackdriver account.  This will stop the monitoring and not affect your log collecting solution.  To remove the project follow the steps listed here:

- https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/accounts/guide#remove-project

**Remove Project from Stackdriver Account**

- Open the Monitoring console.
- Select the Stackdriver account that contains the project or AWS connector from the drop-down menu at the top-right of the Monitoring console.
- Select Account Settings from the same menu.
- On the "Settings" page, click Monitored accounts. You see the following page:
  [image]
- Locate the project or AWS connector you want to remove and select Remove from account from the menu to the right of the project's name.

**Delete Stackdriver Account** (Applicable if you have only 1 account)

Additionally, if you need to delete your stackdriver account, you need to delete the project that is hosting your stackdriver account in the GCP console:

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/accounts/guide#delete-account

> **To delete a Stackdriver account, delete the account's hosting project in the GCP Console.** The hosting project has the same name as the account. **It is not possible to separate the Stackdriver account from the hosting project without deleting the hosting project.**
>
> Stackdriver removes any additional monitored GCP projects or AWS accounts associated with the deleted Stackdriver account. To avoid the loss of monitoring data and logs from these projects, see the sections on Moving projects to a different Stackdriver account, and Merging Stackdriver accounts.

Comment: There is no option to delete the GCP project from Stackdriver - it is the only one in the list of monitored accounts.

Comment: Can anyone provide a method to resolve this please?

Comment: Hi Glen, so the above instructions predominantly cover how to remove monitoring from a GCP project.  It seems like you're in a situation where you're trying to delete the stackdriver account.  Unfortunately, the only way to do that is to delete the GCP project that your stackdriver account is tied to.  The last link I shared addresses that situation (I'll add an edit with quotes from that page): https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/accounts/guide#delete-account

Comment: So you're saying it's impossible to remove Stackdriver from a GCP account, yet you're quite happy to charge extra for it's use if I go above a certain threshold of something I have no control of?  Seems a bit like sharp business practices that you need to review!

Comment: Hi Glen, I'm just a fellow cloud user, no gcp affiliation.  It's not impossible to remove from a GCP account.  It's impossible to remove your stackdriver account from the GCP PROJECT it is tied to without deleting the project.  You can delete the stackdriver account by deleting the GCP project that it is tied to.  Feel free to accept the answer if it's addressed what you've asked for.

Comment: Apologies, you seemed like a bot / support agent.  Yes, the Stack Driver is impossible to remove from a Project - that's my issue.  I don't want monitoring, yet I can't have the project without it and migrating to another project is not a small exercise, hence my frustration with this oversight on Google's part.

Answer (score 3):

You can unlink your GCP project from a Stackdriver workspace by Merging the workspace into a new, blank workspace.

Before following these steps, you will need to create an empty project in GCP that you can later delete.

Make sure to unlink the GCP project that you want to keep from the merged workspace before deleting the empty project that hosts the new workspace.

These instructions are taken from here: https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/workspaces/guide#merge-account

> Merging Workspace A into Workspace B moves all the GCP projects except AWS connector projects from Workspace A to Workspace B. Specifically, here is the effect of merging A into B:
>
> - All GCP projects that were added to Workspace A are moved into Workspace B.
> - All AWS accounts in Workspace A are removed from A. You have to manually add the accounts to Workspace B. You can delete the AWS connector projects unless you need to retrieve the AWS account's logs from them.
>     The project that hosts Workspace A is added to Workspace B, even if the project is empty.
> - The host project is the project you use to create the Workspace. This project typically has resources in the case of a single-project Workspace but is empty for a multi-project Workspace. **Merging is the only way to separate this project from its Workspace.**
> - All the monitoring and other configuration information in Workspace A is deleted. This includes dashboards, alerting policies, uptime checks, and so on. Workspace A no longer exists.
>
> To merge Workspaces, do the following:
>
> 1. Open the Stackdriver Monitoring console.
> 2. If necessary, create Workspace B using an empty project.
> 3. Select the Workspace that is to be kept ("B" in this scenario) from the drop-down menu at the top-right of the Monitoring console.
> 4. Select Workspace Settings from the same menu.
> 5. Click Monitored accounts from the left-side menu.
> 6. Click Merge another Workspace into this one.
> 7. Select the Workspace that is to be removed ("A" in this scenario).
> 8. Read about what information is lost during the merge.
> 9. Click Merge.

You can then delete the newly created empty project/workspace

> Deleting a Workspace
>
> **Before deleting a Workspace**, check if project you used to create the Workspace has resources you want to preserve, **or if the Workspace is still linked to additional GCP projects or AWS accounts**. If so, see Merging Workspaces for a way to move resources to another place before deleting the Workspace.
>
> If your Workspace project has nothing of value, then delete the Workspace by deleting the Workspace's project in the GCP Console. Go to IAM & admin > Settings and click Shut Down.

Comment: Thanks, it's a crazy workaround but worked like a charm!