# How to disable Stackdriver Monitoring in Google Cloud Kubernetes?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-stackdriver

I found this answer: [https://serverfault.com/questions/918671/how-to-disable-stackdriver-monitoring-for-a-project?r=SearchResults&s=1|89.7109](https://serverfault.com/questions/918671/how-to-disable-stackdriver-monitoring-for-a-project?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C89.7109)

But it's from 2 years ago and can't be applied at the moment.

I tried to dig Google Cloud Documentation for a while but haven't find any solutions so far.

Does anyone know how to disable Stackdriver Monitoring service from Google Cloud Console?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Why you can disable tottally GKE's logs? Some special reason?

Comment: I can't find a place to disable Stackdriver Monitoring, since it's causing 40% of my budget increment...

Comment: So, you are talking about the master nodes logs, os nodepool? When you create a GKE cluster, the [Cloud monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke) is enabled by default, and yoyu can disable if you want. Otherwise, the [Audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/audit-logging#audit_logs_in_your_project) is NOT enabled by default, if enabled, it will generate extra billing.

Comment: It works for you ?

Comment: Unfortunately...no, I reached to Google Cloud Support Center already, it could be a bug, let's see...

Comment: OK, please update here if you find something new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after days following up with the Google Support center (costed me 100$/month), I want to post the answer here just in case someone might need it.

1. Stackdriver Monitoring & Logging are completely 2 different definitions, even the Google employee was mistaken at my first ticket, so turning off Logging didn't solve my situation, in fact, it could making the Google Support staffs find it a bit difficult to assist, since the logs won't be pushed to your Cloud Console.

*(You're only charged when the monthly logs are over 50GB, which is very large number)*

2. Disabling "Stackdriver Monitoring API" could stop you from accessing these 3 services also:

- Google Container Registry
- cloudapis.googleapis.com
- file.googleapis.com

*(This is obviously not the solution I wanted)*

3. The reason why I have been charged for Stackdriver Monitoring service: I did installed an application from Google Marketplace - Redis HA, while selecting the options, I did check into "Enabled monitoring", and it will send all the logs of this services/containers to my Monitoring panel, in "Custom Metrics" section.
4. I don't want to remove/reinstall the "Redis HA" service, since there are some of our other services are relying on it, so I have to find a way to disable the "monitoring" option from this service. The support staff guided me with these solutions:

- https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics
- https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics#deleting_metrics

I followed this instruction and it worked as I expected.

***P/S: I actually found another solution, by changing the Deployment configuration of Redis HA service, find & remove the config of monitoring which sending data to "custom.googleapis.com", then you should be good.***

*P/S 2: Think twice when selecting the "Enable monitoring" option of Marketplace Application. It will cost you some real money...*